# conda:what's the difference between conda update and conda upgrade?

Tags: anaconda, conda

`conda update --all`

`conda upgrade --all`

I tried to test the difference

seems that the command`conda upgrade--all` just update to the last version.

and the `conda update --alll` consider compatibility.

so what's the *real difference*?

Comment: Did you look for some documentation? What did you find?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between conda install and conda update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226942/what-is-the-difference-between-conda-install-and-conda-update)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in documentation explains this

```bash
$ conda --help
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.

Options:

positional arguments:
  command
    ...
    update       Updates conda packages to the latest compatible version.
    upgrade      Alias for conda update.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     Show this help message and exit.
...
```

That is, there is no difference; `upgrade` is an alias for `update`.