# What is the difference between codes to Update Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, conda

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter
I installed Jupyter Notebook with below command to my tutorialEnv

```
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

Now the version is 6.4.11 but there is a newer verison 6.4.12
so i first tried

```
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

Nothing changed! it says

## All requested packages already installed.

When i use

```
conda update jupyter
```

Than there are too much file to install

```
    (base) C:\Users\Messi>activate tutorialEnv

(tutorialEnv) C:\Users\Messi>conda update jupyter
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Messi\anaconda3\envs\tutorialEnv

  added / updated specs:
    - jupyter


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    argon2-cffi-21.3.0         |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          15 KB
    argon2-cffi-bindings-21.2.0|   py39h2bbff1b_0          36 KB
    asttokens-2.0.5            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          20 KB
    attrs-21.4.0               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          51 KB
    backcall-0.2.0             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          13 KB
    beautifulsoup4-4.11.1      |   py39haa95532_0         190 KB
    blas-1.0                   |              mkl           6 KB
    bleach-4.1.0               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         123 KB
    certifi-2022.6.15          |   py39haa95532_0         153 KB
    cffi-1.15.1                |   py39h2bbff1b_0         218 KB
    colorama-0.4.5             |   py39haa95532_0          28 KB
    cryptography-37.0.1        |   py39h21b164f_0         977 KB
    debugpy-1.5.1              |   py39hd77b12b_0         2.6 MB
    decorator-5.1.1            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          12 KB
    defusedxml-0.7.1           |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          23 KB
    entrypoints-0.4            |   py39haa95532_0          17 KB
    executing-0.8.3            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          18 KB
    glib-2.69.1                |       h5dc1a3c_1         1.6 MB
    gst-plugins-base-1.18.5    |       h9e645db_0         1.7 MB
    gstreamer-1.18.5           |       hd78058f_0         1.7 MB
    intel-openmp-2021.4.0      |    haa95532_3556         2.2 MB
    ipykernel-6.9.1            |   py39haa95532_0         200 KB
    ipython-8.4.0              |   py39haa95532_0        1009 KB
    ipython_genutils-0.2.0     |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          27 KB
    ipywidgets-7.6.5           |     pyhd3eb1b0_1         105 KB
    jedi-0.18.1                |   py39haa95532_1         982 KB
    jinja2-3.0.3               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         106 KB
    jpeg-9e                    |       h2bbff1b_0         292 KB
    jsonschema-4.4.0           |   py39haa95532_0         139 KB
    jupyter-1.0.0              |   py39haa95532_8           7 KB
    jupyter_client-7.2.2       |   py39haa95532_0         216 KB
    jupyter_console-6.4.3      |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          23 KB
    jupyter_core-4.10.0        |   py39haa95532_0          96 KB
    jupyter_server-1.18.1      |   py39haa95532_0         372 KB
    jupyterlab-3.4.4           |   py39haa95532_0         3.8 MB
    jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2  |             py_0           8 KB
    jupyterlab_server-2.12.0   |   py39haa95532_0          83 KB
    jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0   |     pyhd3eb1b0_1         109 KB
    libclang-12.0.0            |default_h627e005_2        17.8 MB
    libffi-3.4.2               |       hd77b12b_4         107 KB
    libogg-1.3.5               |       h2bbff1b_1          33 KB
    libpng-1.6.37              |       h2a8f88b_0         333 KB
    libsodium-1.0.18           |       h62dcd97_0         477 KB
    libvorbis-1.3.7            |       he774522_0         202 KB
    libxml2-2.9.14             |       h0ad7f3c_0         1.5 MB
    libxslt-1.1.35             |       h2bbff1b_0         407 KB
    markupsafe-2.1.1           |   py39h2bbff1b_0          26 KB
    matplotlib-inline-0.1.2    |     pyhd3eb1b0_2          12 KB
    mistune-0.8.4              |py39h2bbff1b_1000          57 KB
    mkl-2021.4.0               |     haa95532_640       114.9 MB
    mkl-service-2.4.0          |   py39h2bbff1b_0          51 KB
    mkl_fft-1.3.1              |   py39h277e83a_0         139 KB
    mkl_random-1.2.2           |   py39hf11a4ad_0         225 KB
    nbclient-0.5.13            |   py39haa95532_0         108 KB
    nbconvert-6.4.4            |   py39haa95532_0         517 KB
    nbformat-5.3.0             |   py39haa95532_0         146 KB
    nest-asyncio-1.5.5         |   py39haa95532_0          16 KB
    notebook-6.4.12            |   py39haa95532_0         4.6 MB
    packaging-21.3             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          36 KB
    pandocfilters-1.5.0        |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          11 KB
    parso-0.8.3                |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          70 KB
    pcre-8.45                  |       hd77b12b_0         382 KB
    pickleshare-0.7.5          |  pyhd3eb1b0_1003          13 KB
    ply-3.11                   |   py39haa95532_0          81 KB
    prometheus_client-0.14.1   |   py39haa95532_0          89 KB
    prompt-toolkit-3.0.20      |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         259 KB
    prompt_toolkit-3.0.20      |       hd3eb1b0_0          12 KB
    pure_eval-0.2.2            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          14 KB
    pycparser-2.21             |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          94 KB
    pygments-2.11.2            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         759 KB
    pyopenssl-22.0.0           |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          50 KB
    pyparsing-3.0.4            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          81 KB
    pyqt-5.15.7                |   py39hd77b12b_0         3.7 MB
    pyqt5-sip-12.11.0          |   py39hd77b12b_0          75 KB
    pyrsistent-0.18.0          |   py39h196d8e1_0          90 KB
    python-dateutil-2.8.2      |     pyhd3eb1b0_0         233 KB
    python-fastjsonschema-2.15.1|     pyhd3eb1b0_0          29 KB
    pytz-2022.1                |   py39haa95532_0         195 KB
    pywin32-302                |   py39h2bbff1b_2         5.6 MB
    pywinpty-2.0.2             |   py39h5da7b33_0         200 KB
    pyzmq-23.2.0               |   py39hd77b12b_0         404 KB
    qt-main-5.15.2             |       he8e5bd7_7        50.0 MB
    qt-webengine-5.15.9        |       hb9a9bb5_4        48.9 MB
    qtconsole-5.3.1            |   py39haa95532_1         192 KB
    qtpy-2.0.1                 |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          40 KB
    qtwebkit-5.212             |       h3ad3cdb_4        10.3 MB
    requests-2.28.1            |   py39haa95532_0          99 KB
    send2trash-1.8.0           |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          19 KB
    setuptools-61.2.0          |   py39haa95532_0         1.0 MB
    sip-6.6.2                  |   py39hd77b12b_0         434 KB
    six-1.16.0                 |     pyhd3eb1b0_1          18 KB
    soupsieve-2.3.1            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          34 KB
    stack_data-0.2.0           |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          22 KB
    terminado-0.13.1           |   py39haa95532_0          31 KB
    testpath-0.6.0             |   py39haa95532_0          85 KB
    tornado-6.1                |   py39h2bbff1b_0         598 KB
    traitlets-5.1.1            |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          84 KB
    typing-extensions-4.3.0    |   py39haa95532_0           9 KB
    typing_extensions-4.3.0    |   py39haa95532_0          42 KB
    tzdata-2022a               |       hda174b7_0         109 KB
    urllib3-1.26.11            |   py39haa95532_0         184 KB
    vc-14.2                    |       h21ff451_1           8 KB
    vs2015_runtime-14.27.29016 |       h5e58377_2        1007 KB
    wcwidth-0.2.5              |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          26 KB
    webencodings-0.5.1         |   py39haa95532_1          20 KB
    wheel-0.37.1               |     pyhd3eb1b0_0          33 KB
    widgetsnbextension-3.5.2   |   py39haa95532_0         646 KB
    wincertstore-0.2           |   py39haa95532_2          15 KB
    winpty-0.4.3               |                4         678 KB
    zeromq-4.3.4               |       hd77b12b_0         4.2 MB
    zlib-1.2.12                |       h8cc25b3_2         116 KB
    zstd-1.5.2                 |       h19a0ad4_0         509 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       292.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  anyio              pkgs/main/win-64::anyio-3.5.0-py39haa95532_0
  babel              pkgs/main/noarch::babel-2.9.1-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  brotlipy           pkgs/main/win-64::brotlipy-0.7.0-py39h2bbff1b_1003
  charset-normalizer pkgs/main/noarch::charset-normalizer-2.0.4-pyhd3eb1b0
  cryptography       pkgs/main/win-64::cryptography-37.0.1-py39h21b164f_0
  glib               pkgs/main/win-64::glib-2.69.1-h5dc1a3c_1
  gst-plugins-base   pkgs/main/win-64::gst-plugins-base-1.18.5-h9e645db_0
  gstreamer          pkgs/main/win-64::gstreamer-1.18.5-hd78058f_0
  idna               pkgs/main/noarch::idna-3.3-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  json5              pkgs/main/noarch::json5-0.9.6-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  jupyter_server     pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_server-1.18.1-py39haa95532_
  jupyterlab         pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab-3.4.4-py39haa95532_0
  jupyterlab_server  pkgs/main/win-64::jupyterlab_server-2.12.0-py39haa955
  libclang           pkgs/main/win-64::libclang-12.0.0-default_h627e005_2
  libffi             pkgs/main/win-64::libffi-3.4.2-hd77b12b_4
  libiconv           pkgs/main/win-64::libiconv-1.16-h2bbff1b_2
  libogg             pkgs/main/win-64::libogg-1.3.5-h2bbff1b_1
  libsodium          pkgs/main/win-64::libsodium-1.0.18-h62dcd97_0
  libvorbis          pkgs/main/win-64::libvorbis-1.3.7-he774522_0
  libwebp            pkgs/main/win-64::libwebp-1.2.2-h2bbff1b_0
  libxml2            pkgs/main/win-64::libxml2-2.9.14-h0ad7f3c_0
  libxslt            pkgs/main/win-64::libxslt-1.1.35-h2bbff1b_0
  lz4-c              pkgs/main/win-64::lz4-c-1.9.3-h2bbff1b_1
  nbclassic          pkgs/main/noarch::nbclassic-0.3.5-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pcre               pkgs/main/win-64::pcre-8.45-hd77b12b_0
  ply                pkgs/main/win-64::ply-3.11-py39haa95532_0
  pyopenssl          pkgs/main/noarch::pyopenssl-22.0.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  pyqt5-sip          pkgs/main/win-64::pyqt5-sip-12.11.0-py39hd77b12b_0
  pysocks            pkgs/main/win-64::pysocks-1.7.1-py39haa95532_0
  pytz               pkgs/main/win-64::pytz-2022.1-py39haa95532_0
  qt-main            pkgs/main/win-64::qt-main-5.15.2-he8e5bd7_7
  qt-webengine       pkgs/main/win-64::qt-webengine-5.15.9-hb9a9bb5_4
  qtwebkit           pkgs/main/win-64::qtwebkit-5.212-h3ad3cdb_4
  requests           pkgs/main/win-64::requests-2.28.1-py39haa95532_0
  sniffio            pkgs/main/win-64::sniffio-1.2.0-py39haa95532_1
  toml               pkgs/main/noarch::toml-0.10.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  urllib3            pkgs/main/win-64::urllib3-1.26.11-py39haa95532_0
  websocket-client   pkgs/main/win-64::websocket-client-0.58.0-py39haa9553
  win_inet_pton      pkgs/main/win-64::win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py39haa95532_0
  zeromq             pkgs/main/win-64::zeromq-4.3.4-hd77b12b_0
  zstd               pkgs/main/win-64::zstd-1.5.2-h19a0ad4_0

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    anaconda::ca-certificates-2022.4.26-h~ --> pkgs/main:
rtificates-2022.07.19-haa95532_0
  cffi                 anaconda::cffi-1.15.0-py39h2bbff1b_1 --> pkgs/main:
1.15.1-py39h2bbff1b_0
  colorama           anaconda/noarch::colorama-0.4.4-pyhd3~ --> pkgs/main/
::colorama-0.4.5-py39haa95532_0
  ipython            anaconda::ipython-8.3.0-py39haa95532_0 --> pkgs/main:
on-8.4.0-py39haa95532_0
  jupyter            anaconda::jupyter-1.0.0-py39haa95532_7 --> pkgs/main:
er-1.0.0-py39haa95532_8
  notebook           anaconda::notebook-6.4.11-py39haa9553~ --> pkgs/main:
ook-6.4.12-py39haa95532_0
  openssl               anaconda::openssl-1.1.1o-h2bbff1b_0 --> pkgs/main:
sl-1.1.1q-h2bbff1b_0
  pip                   anaconda::pip-21.2.4-py39haa95532_0 --> pkgs/main:
2.1.2-py39haa95532_0
  prometheus_client  anaconda/noarch::prometheus_client-0.~ --> pkgs/main/
::prometheus_client-0.14.1-py39haa95532_0
  pyqt                  anaconda::pyqt-5.9.2-py39hd77b12b_6 --> pkgs/main:
5.15.7-py39hd77b12b_0
  pyzmq               anaconda::pyzmq-22.3.0-py39hd77b12b_2 --> pkgs/main:
-23.2.0-py39hd77b12b_0
  qtconsole          anaconda/noarch::qtconsole-5.3.0-pyhd~ --> pkgs/main/
::qtconsole-5.3.1-py39haa95532_1
  sip                  anaconda::sip-4.19.13-py39hd77b12b_0 --> pkgs/main:
.6.2-py39hd77b12b_0
  sqlite                 anaconda::sqlite-3.38.5-h2bbff1b_0 --> pkgs/main:
e-3.39.2-h2bbff1b_0
  typing-extensions  anaconda/noarch::typing-extensions-4.~ --> pkgs/main/
::typing-extensions-4.3.0-py39haa95532_0
  typing_extensions  anaconda/noarch::typing_extensions-4.~ --> pkgs/main/
::typing_extensions-4.3.0-py39haa95532_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  argon2-cffi                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  argon2-cffi-bindi~                               anaconda --> pkgs/main
  asttokens                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  attrs                                            anaconda --> pkgs/main
  backcall                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  beautifulsoup4                                   anaconda --> pkgs/main
  blas                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
  bleach                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  certifi                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  debugpy                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  decorator                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  defusedxml                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  entrypoints                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  executing                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  intel-openmp                                     anaconda --> pkgs/main
  ipykernel                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  ipython_genutils                                 anaconda --> pkgs/main
  ipywidgets                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jedi                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jinja2                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jpeg                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jsonschema                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jupyter_client                                   anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jupyter_console                                  anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jupyter_core                                     anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jupyterlab_pygmen~                               anaconda --> pkgs/main
  jupyterlab_widgets                               anaconda --> pkgs/main
  libpng                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  markupsafe                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  matplotlib-inline                                anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mistune                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mkl                                              anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mkl-service                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mkl_fft                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  mkl_random                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  nbclient                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  nbconvert                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  nbformat                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  nest-asyncio                                     anaconda --> pkgs/main
  packaging                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pandocfilters                                    anaconda --> pkgs/main
  parso                                            anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pickleshare                                      anaconda --> pkgs/main
  prompt-toolkit                                   anaconda --> pkgs/main
  prompt_toolkit                                   anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pure_eval                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pycparser                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pygments                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pyparsing                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pyrsistent                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  python-dateutil                                  anaconda --> pkgs/main
  python-fastjsonsc~                               anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pywin32                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  pywinpty                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  qtpy                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
  send2trash                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  setuptools                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  six                                              anaconda --> pkgs/main
  soupsieve                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  stack_data                                       anaconda --> pkgs/main
  terminado                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  testpath                                         anaconda --> pkgs/main
  tornado                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  traitlets                                        anaconda --> pkgs/main
  tzdata                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  vc                                               anaconda --> pkgs/main
  vs2015_runtime                                   anaconda --> pkgs/main
  wcwidth                                          anaconda --> pkgs/main
  webencodings                                     anaconda --> pkgs/main
  wheel                                            anaconda --> pkgs/main
  widgetsnbextension                               anaconda --> pkgs/main
  wincertstore                                     anaconda --> pkgs/main
  winpty                                           anaconda --> pkgs/main
  zlib                                             anaconda --> pkgs/main
```

what is the difference between
conda update jupyter and conda update -c anaconda jupyter?
If i use conda update jupyter is this make problem?
I always use conda install -c anaconda package name.

Thanks for comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here is in the channels used. According to [the docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-repositories/), by default, your anaconda installation is configured to look in the channels

```
main
r
msys2 (on windows)
free (conda<4.7)
```

The `anaconda` channel is only a mirror of `main`, so it is not needed when doing `conda install` and can even lead to the strange behavior you are seeing. When multiple channels are specified, conda - by default - has a strict channel priority, meaning that packages will always be installed from the first channel they are available from. See [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) for more details.

Now let's take a look at the commands you use

```
conda install -c anaconda jupyter
conda update jupyter
```

The first command prepends the `anaconda` channel to your list of channels, making it the highest priority channel. This will result in all packages being installed from the `anaconda` channel (which you can also see when doing `conda list` or in the output of the installation).

In the second command, only the default channels are used, making `main` the highest priority channel. Two things are now happening, which you both see in your output `The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:` happens because `conda` now things all packages should be coming from main, even if the same version is already installed from the `anaconda` channel due to the channel priority. `The following packages will be UPDATED:` happens either because there actually is a higher version available on the `main` channel (which was previously ignored because of `anaconda` having higher priority in the previous command) or the build number differs and conda just treats it as a higher version, e.g. `anaconda::jupyter-1.0.0-py39haa95532_7 --> pkgs/main: er-1.0.0-py39haa95532_8`

**Takeaway**
There should be no real need to explicitly state `-c anaconda`  but if you use it, you need to do so on subsequent calls also, otherwise a lot of packages will be reinstalled frequently. Alternatively, you can disable the strict channel priority, but that could slow down the solving step of `conda`.

As for the difference between `install` and `update`: They will both attempt to install the newest version, but behave differently for packages that are not installed. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52226942/what-is-the-difference-between-conda-install-and-conda-update)